# Why no app.yaml file in DrEdit PHP files from Git Hub?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, app.yaml

I thought that Google App Engine needed an [`app.yaml`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_About_app_yaml) configuration file to correctly access all the files?

There is no `app.yaml` file provided in the [DrEdit for PHP](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/tree/master/php) files from GitHub. Can I run a PHP app in Google App Engine without an `app.yaml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you always need an `app.yaml` file.

The [README.md file on the DrEdit for PHP](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/tree/master/php) GitHub repository does appear to be a little confusing, it appears to be a Google Drive application (meaning it demonstrates interaction with the Drive API) that is written in pure PHP. Even though the first line of the setup instructions tell you to create an App Engine app, further down it tells you to copy the source to a folder on your web server, and does not mention anywhere about an app.yaml file.

There is no reason why you could not run it on App Engine though, you will just need to create an appropiate `app.yaml` file. I have not tested it but something like this may work:

```
application: replace-with-your-app-id
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

Comment: I have created [an *issue*](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/issues/17) on the repository for that project, too highlight this.